# ¿Qué es la rama master en git?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Cuando creo un proyecto nuevo en git este contiene una y solo una rama, la rama master:

```
~> cd test
~/test> echo "Prueba de git" > Readme.md
~/test> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jose/test/.git/
~/test> git add .
~/test> git commit -m "Prueba git"
Created initial commit 0babea8: Prueba git
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Readme.md
~/test> git branch
* master
```

Si clono un proyecto me encuentro que puede tener muchas ramas remotas:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/git/git
$ cd git
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/maint
  origin/master
  origin/next
  origin/pu
  origin/todo
```

Y que como resultado del clonar hay una sola rama local, la rama master:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

¿Tiene algo de especial la rama master, es diferente de las ramas que creo con `git branch`? ¿Es obligatoria? ¿Pasará algo malo si la borro?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cuando clonas un repositorio clonas también sus ramas, no sólo la `master` (la maestra, la que se crea por defecto), pero las guarda dentro del repositorio "remoto" y no la hace "local" hasta que usemos `checkout`.

Usando `git branch -a` podrás ver todas y usando `git checkout todo` podrás cambiar a la rama `todo` y ver que cambia el contenido del repositorio, momento a partir del cual también podrás ver esa rama como local usando `git branch -a`.

Échale un vistazo a la documentación: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Ramas-Remotas

> Activando (*checkout*) una rama local a partir de una rama remota, se
>   crea automáticamente lo que podríamos denominar "una rama de
>   seguimiento" (*tracking branch*) [...]
>
> Si estás en una rama de seguimiento y
>   tecleas el comando `git push`, Git sabe automáticamente a qué servidor y
>   a qué rama ha de llevar los contenidos [...]
>
> Cuando clonas un repositorio, este suele crear automáticamente una
>   rama `master` que hace seguimiento de `origin/master`. Y es por eso que
>   `git push` y `git pull` trabajan directamente, sin necesidad de más
>   argumentos.

---

### Respuestas:

**¿Tiene algo de especial la rama master?**

Es la que se crea por defecto, y como verás en el resto de mis respuestas no tiene nada más de especial.

NOTA: Hay que tener en cuenta que algunas aplicaciones podrían presuponer que esa rama debería existir. Además, tal y como expongo en los comentarios, si borras la rama `master` deberías borrar cualquier referencia (incluso un `HEAD`) que apunte a un commit de éste.

**¿Es diferente de las ramas que creo con git branch?**

No.

**¿Es obligatoria?**

No.

**¿Pasará algo malo si la borro?**

No, se borrará como cualquier otra rama, pero previamente tendrás que hacer un `checkout` a una rama diferente (o crearla si no tienes otras ramas):

```
  $ git branch -D master
error: Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.

  $ git checkout todo
Branch todo set up to track remote branch todo from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'todo'

  $ git branch -D master
Eliminada la rama master (era b14f27f)
```

Comment: HEAD apunta al último commit de la rama, por lo que es probable que el último commit fuera borrado. También ten en cuenta que muchos servicios (como github y gitlab) y aplicaciones (el propio comando `git`) suele presuponer la existencia de esa rama para considerarla como la maestra. Luego le echo un vistazo a qué le pasa a ese repositorio. Nunca he tenido la necesidad de borrar la rama "master", así que nunca he estudiado en profundidad sus implicaciones. Por cierto, ¿has probado a hacer el clonado y checkout de una rama directa en vez de a la de por defecto? `git clone -b rama ...`

Comment: Podría verse como una ventaja presuponer que esa rama existirá. Ya había pensado en editar mi respuesta para anotar que habría aplicaciones que podrían presuponer su existencia y provocar algún error si no la encuentran. Es como el usuario "root". No es necesario que se llame así, incluso podría haber más de un usuario con uid 0, pero habría posibilidad de que haya aplicaciones que fallen si no lo encuentra.

Comment: Me parece que sería una buena edición. Y con eso podría darle la marquita.

Comment: Agregada edición. Tened en cuenta que he arreglado el tema de las referencias en el fork que he hecho: https://github.com/ojgarciab/gittest (`remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/rama`).

Comment: Comentario insignificante: `HEAD` no apunta al último commit de una rama. `HEAD` siempre apunta a donde estás parado, que es tentador pensar que es _la ultima revisión de una rama_, pero ese no es siempre el caso. Por ejemplo: `git checkout main~5`. Donde está `HEAD` ahora? 5 revisiones detrás de la última revisión de `main`.

Comment: Bien visto @eftshift0, gracias por la puntualización. Por desgracia borraron el comentario previo (y creo que alguno posterior) por lo que no se aprecia a qué hacía referencia esa (breve) explicación. Han pasado más de cuatro años y ya no me acuerdo, pero creo que era un tema de referencias que no podían resolverse.

Answer (score 0):

Reusmiendo se puede decir que es la primera que se crea. Su uso suele ir destinado a ser la rama principal del proyecto, en donde se encuentra o debería de encontrar siempre la última versión estable y funcional de producción del proyecto.

El resto de ramas se suelen utilizar para realizar modificaciones al proyecto, como puedne ser develop, hotfix, beta, etc... Y una vez esa versión este probada y finalziada, se sube como versión definitiva a la rama master.

[En la página oficial de GIT explican exactamente todo el funcionamiento de la rama máster](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git-%C2%BFQu%C3%A9-es-una-rama%3F).

Answer (score 0):

Las ramas son utilizadas para desarrollar funcionalidades aisladas unas de otras. La rama master es la rama "por defecto" cuando creas un repositorio. Crea nuevas ramas durante el desarrollo y fusiónalas a la rama principal cuando termines.
Crea una nueva rama llamada "feature_x" y cámbiate a ella usando

```
git checkout -b feature_x
```

vuelve a la rama principal

```
git checkout master
```

y borra la rama

```
git branch -d feature_x
```

Una rama nueva no estará disponible para los demás a menos que subas (push) la rama a tu repositorio remoto

```
git push origin <branch>
```

**Origen de la fuente:** http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html